Why is Gitflow release operation doing so many actions in Bitbucket
I learned that release action in GitFlow is merely a merge develop branch (latest update) to the release/XXX branch with a TAG on it.
I would like to do simply as following:
git checkout -b release/XXX
git tag V1.0
git push

When I try this on Bitbucket, after I click start and finish New Release, I get an additional operation on commit log (see image below):

green arrow: trigger release process in Bitbucket
red arrow: another merge from main branch back to develop (which makes me confuse why it is needed).



It seems that Bitbucket does the following when I try to release with GIT-FLOW:
// on develop branch
git checkout -b release/V1.0  //#1
git tag V1.0                  //#2
git checkout main             //#3
git merge release/V1.0        //#4
git checkout develop          //#5
git merge main                //#6

Why is the main branch involved (step #3~#5) during release? Also, why is an additional merge back to develop needed (step6), and what is the changes in main branch?

This is happening because you are finishing the release right after you start it:

When I try this on Bitbucket, after I click start and finish New Release...

"Starting" the release is what creates the release branch pointing to develop at that time, and "Finishing" the release merges it into main, and then merges main into develop. You simply need to "Start" the release first. Then merge your commits into the release branch and when you're done testing and ready to release that into production, that's when you finish it. The merge into main signifies you've deployed to production. In this way the main branch always represents what's in production. The merge back into develop makes sure that all of the new code on the release branch has made it's way back into develop so you don't lose it.
